# node, returns empty object on require

Tags: javascript, node.js

My server.js file:

```
let express = require('express'),
..
..
let server = express();

server.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
..
server.set('isProduction',true);

let routes = require('./routes');

function routesSetup(server) {
  server.use('/api', routes);
}

function start(){
  ...
  console.log('app server up and running on 127.0.0.1:3000);
}

exports.start = start;
exports.server = server;
```

My index.js file with path `routes/adduser/index.js`

```
   let srv = require("../../server");
   console.log(srv.server.get('isProduction')) // cant read get of undefined...
   console.log(srv.server) // undefined
   console.log(srv) // {}
```

Why is `srv` an empty object? I need to access the server so I can check a variable set in server.js

Comment: Are you sure there are no cyclic requires between server and index?

Comment: try with: `let srv = require("../../server").server;` or `import {server} from "../../server"`

Comment: I just tested your code and its working fine. I created exactly your structures of folders and 2 files (server and index). And it logged both server object and start function. So can you tell me how are you running index.js file.

Comment: ya, even i tried, everything working fine.

Comment: everything working for me as well. You might want to try a reinstall of express npm i -S express

Comment: @myke_11j, I updated my question so you can se how index.js is run.